# How to convert the values of a hash from String to Array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I'm looking to perform a conversion of the values in a Ruby hash from String to Integer.

I thought this would be fairly similar to the way you perform a conversion in a Ruby array (using the map method), but I have not been able to find an elegant solution that doesn't involve converting the hash to an array, flattening it, etc.

Is there a clean solution to do this?

Eg. From

```
x = { "a" => "1", "b" => "2", "c"=> "3" }
```

To

```
x = { "a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My preferred solution:

```
Hash[x.map { |k, v| [k, v.to_i]}] #=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}
```

A somewhat wasteful one (has to iterate over the values twice):

```
Hash[x.keys.zip(x.values.map(&:to_i))] #=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}
```

Comment: thanks! this solution seems like the one i would use. I thought there would be something that used the map function.

Comment: Note that this answer creates an intermediate Array (`Enumerable#map` always returns an `Array`), so for big Hashes it's better to use my solution.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid modifying the original Hash (unlike the existing answers), I'd use

```
newhash = x.reduce({}) do |h, (k, v)|
  h[k] = v.to_i and h
end
```

If you're using Ruby 1.9, you can also use `Enumerable#each_with_object` to achieve the same effect a bit more cleanly.

```
newhash = x.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), h|
  h[k] = v.to_i
end
```

If you want to, you can also extract the logic into a module and extend the `Hash` class with it.

```
module HMap
  def hmap
    self.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), h|
      h[k] = yield(k, v)
    end
  end
end

class Hash
  include HMap
end
```

Now you can use

```
newhash = x.hmap { |k, v| v.to_i } # => {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}
```

Comment: Great thorough answer, very well detailed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
x.each{|k,v| x[k]=v.to_i}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p.keys.map { |key| p[key] = p[key].to_i }
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The block parameters are in the wrong place and neither `Array` or `Enumerable` have a method called `to_map`.

Comment: `p.keys.map { |key| p[key] = p[key].to_i }` is what you meant.

Comment: to_map was my custom method.. just forgot that.. thanks for correction